# Guardar ion-items en mongobd

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, ionic4

Hola estoy cargando unos ion-items desde un wheel picker, hasta ahí todo bien, necesito guardar estos información en la una colección de datos en Mongodb, pero no se como, necesito algun consejo o guia para poder continuar.

(tengo toda la logica y conexion a la base de datos, pero no se como hacer el recorrido de esa lista)

codigo donde cargo la info desde el wheel picker

```
<ion-list #lista>           
          <ion-item-sliding  *ngFor="let mat of tempMat" >             
            <ion-item>             
              <ion-input [(ngModel)]="materialesObra.nombre">                          
                  <p>{{mat}}</p>                       
              </ion-input>
              <ion-input [(ngModel)]="materialesObra.cantidad"                          
                         text-center                         
                         id="cant"
                         value = "0">       
              </ion-input>    
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item-options side="start">                          
              <ion-item-option>
                <ion-icon (click)="borrar(mat)" slot="icon-only" name="trash" ></ion-icon>
              </ion-item-option>

            </ion-item-options>         

          </ion-item-sliding>

        </ion-list>
```

Alguna sugerencia, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, el código que subes es del *frontend*, se necesita implementar toda la lógica de conexión a la base de datos en el *backend*. Por lo tanto deberías primero crear en tu servidor Node una conexión a MongoDB, los modelos de tus datos y el resto de la lógica para manipularlos. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad ya tengo toda esa logica implementada pero no se como recorrer toda esa lista, siempre me guarda el primer item, perdon por no haberlo mencionado antes

Comment: En mongo hay una operación que se llama `insertMany( )` que te permite guardar varios registros. Como estas mandando los datos a mongo?